# Curl only save if not 404

Tags: python, curl, download

I'm writing a python program for downloading some pictures of students at my school.

Here is my code: `

```
import os
count = 0
max_c = 1000000
while max_c >= count:
    os.system("curl http://www.tjoernegaard.dk/Faelles/ElevFotos/"+str(count)+".jpg > "+str(count)+".jpg")
    count=count+1
```

`

The problem is that i only want so save the jpg if the image exists on the server (not 404), and since i don't have all the image names on the server, i have to send a request for all images between 0 and 1000000, but not all images between 0 and 1000000 exists. So i only want so save the image if it exists on the server. How do i do this (ubuntu)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib2
import sys

for i in range(1000000):
  try:
    pic = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.tjoernegaard.dk/Faelles/ElevFotos/"+str(i)+".jpg").read()
    with open(str(i).zfill(7)+".jpg") as f:
      f.write(pic)
    print "SUCCESS "+str(i)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
  except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "ERROR("+str(e.code)+") "+str(i)
```

should work, a 404 throws an exception

Comment: Ugh, don't use `+` like this, its unpythonic. Use `%s` and such.

Comment: I find the % syntax to be cumbersome and "".format() does not make it better. Therefore i dont even bother to obey the god given law of pythonic-ness in small scripts.

Comment: yup, the "+" syntax is discouraged mostly because of performance and security issues; if neither is a concern, who cares.

Comment: Code snippets needn't be linted. Seriously guys, it's just a proof of concept not a prototype, lower the bar a bit.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the "`-f`" arg to fail silently (not printing HTTP errors), eg:

```
curl -f site.com/file.jpg
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `urllib` library provided by python for your purpose.

```
count = 0
max_c = 1000000
while max_c >= count:
    resp = urllib.urlopen("http://www.tjoernegaard.dk/Faelles/ElevFotos/"+str(count)+".jpg")
    if resp.getcode() == 404:
      //do nothing
    else:
    // do what you got to do.

   count=count+1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I discovery in bash you can use `--fail` and it will silent fail. If the page is an error, it will NOT download...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, I think, would be to use `wget` instead of `curl`, which will discard 404 responses automatically.